# How to handle fancybox popup through Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, fancybox, webdriverwait

I'm trying to handle authentication popup using the code below:

```
driver.get("https://www.printvenue.com");
System.out.println("Successfully opened the Printvenue");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.id("login_li")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
Set <String> handles =driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> it = handles.iterator();
String parent = it.next();
String child = it.next();
driver.switchTo().window(child);
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");
```

But i am not able to enter the email in email test box.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have no windows to switch to, so you don`t need to use the switch.

Your login pop-up is attached to the main DOM so you can write directly in it.
Because your elements are not unique at all, you will have to use the findElements method.

I have tested below code in Firefox and works:

```
driver.get("https://www.printvenue.com");
System.out.println("Successfully opened the Printvenue");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.id("login_li")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
List<WebElement> emailElement = driver.findElements(By.id("email"));
System.out.println(emailElement.size()); // this will tell you how many elements with this ID you have in your DOM
emailElement.get(3).sendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a popup, it's a [Lightbox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_(JavaScript)).

Thankfully this makes it really easy to deal with, it's just standard HTML inside a standard DOM.  The solution to your problem is:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);
    driver.get("https://www.printvenue.com");

    System.out.println("Successfully opened the Printvenue");

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("login_li"))).click();
    WebElement emailElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("email")));
    emailElement.sendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");
```

Well, that should be the solution to your problem at any rate.  The real issue that you are seeing here is that there are 4 elements on the page (at the time of writing this) that share an ID that is supposed to be unique.  This is a problem your developers need to fix because this HTML is not W3C compliant!  I would raise it as a bug and get them to fix it.

You can work around the problem using code like this:

```
    List<WebElement> emailElements = driver.findElements(By.id("email"));
    System.out.println(String.format("Oh dear, there are %s instances of the id email when there should only be 1...", emailElements.size()));
    emailElements.get(3).sendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");
```

However I would encourage you not to do this, it's something that really needs to be fixed!

Comment: If you have found any of the responses useful please upvote them.  If one of the answers has solved your problem please select it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The *authentication popup* which you are referring is technically termed as **fancybox**. To send a *character sequebce* within the **Email** field you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
  chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
  //chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");
  chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions); 
  driver.get("https://www.printvenue.com/");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Login"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.fancybox-outer input[id='email']"))).sendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: printvenue]